# How can I have multiple params (with at least one mandatory) in a function?

Tags: powershell

I want to build a function `foo` that requires at least one string to be added. More (unspecified amount) can be added, but is not necessary.

I created a function similar to this:

```
function foo {
   [CmdLetBinding()]
   param(
       [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string]$param1
   )

   if ($args -ne $null) {
       $string = $param1 + " " + $($args -join ' ')
   } else {
       $string = $param1
   }

   Write-Output $string
   
}
```

However, running `foo a b c` (expected output is `a b c`) fails with

```
foo : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'b'.
At line:1 char:1
+ foo a b c
```

**What do I have to change for this code to work?**

Comment: Do you expect powershell to join/concatenate the individual arguments into a single string, or are you interested in consuming them as an array of strings inside the functions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To implicitly bind straggling arguments to a named parameter, you'll want to set [the `ValueFromRemainingArguments` flag](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions_advanced_parameters#valuefromremainingarguments-argument) in the `[Parameter()]` attribute of the target parameter:

```bsh
param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, ValueFromRemainingArguments=$true)][string]$param1
)
```

```
PS C:\> foo a b c
a b c
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.
This solved my issue. All the kudos to you, good Sir! ;-)

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions_advanced_parameters?view=powershell-7#attributes-of-parameters
for an extensive list.

Comment: @ITM I updated the answer with a link to the `about_Functions_Advannced_Parameters` document as well :)